# How do I create a history-aware cd command?

Tags: bash, macos, unix, sh

I would like to be able to do the following:

```
  /my/old/dir/here $    cd my/new/dir
  /my/new/dir $ cd ^   
  /my/old/dir/here $
```

In other words, I'd like to be able to cd "back". Is there an existing utility and/or an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `cd -`, which does exactly that.

Comment: Wow, this is awesome!! Thank you.

Comment: Now, is there an equivalent of `cd --`? It works, but does not do what I expected.

Comment: And there does not seem to be a 'cd +'

Comment: `--` as an argument means "treat the following words, if any, as arguments, not options". Since there *are* no more words after `--`, it's equivalent to `cd` alone.

Comment: Thank you @chepner. This could have been an answer.